# Installing Jupyter Notebook for Julia in Windows 10

Tags: anaconda, julia, jupyter-notebook, ijulia-notebook

In Windows 10, I have done the following steps:

1º Install Julia.

2º In Julia shell:

```
Pkg.add("Ijulia")
INFO: Package IJulia is already installed
```

3º Launch the jupyter notebook from the Anaconda Prompt:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Then, the jupyter  notebook is launched, however the Julia notebook option does not appear.
Any idea about what is happening??

Thank-you.

Comment: Have you tried typing `using IJulia`, and then `notebook()` from the Julia command prompt?

Comment: Soundly like the spec is not being put somewhere jupyter can find it.
try `Pkg.build("IJulia")` which should try and install the spec again.
Hopefully either succeeding, or failing with a useful error.
If that doesn't work my bet is still on the spec not being found by your anaconda copy of jupyter.
But debugging why  might be tricky